# Is it possible to return something like this in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, return

I'm making a chess program and want to make a function that checks the directions a piece can move.

For example, if the piece is a queen, the function will check how far in each direction the queen can move before hitting the edge of the board or running into another piece. I want to return something that will have a numerical value for each direction, North, Northeast, South, etc
Something like this

return [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2]

Can I return various numbers like that to an array?

Comment: erm... yes. Do I get the points? Perhaps you should post a little bit more to work with

Comment: What "direction" does a knight move?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Clockwise: NNE, ENE, ESE, SSE, SSW, WSW, WNW, NNW. How far it can move in those directions is either 0 or √5

Comment: Yes, @MSalters, but that means a simple eight-element array of integers won't do, and I just wanted to make sure Fro had considered that. It might need 16, unless we assume for knights that the directions have been rotated 22.5 degrees. Over all, it just doesn't seem like the right data structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return an array from a function -- but you can return a vector, which is what you should probably be using instead of an array in any case.

Comment: You can return an `std::array<>` or `boost::array<>`, which are more appropriate than `std::vector<>` when the size is fixed and known at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a structure, you can return a pointer to an array (if you declare it on the heap using malloc)...

Answer (score 0):

You can return more than one value in a C++ function by passing aditional arguments by reference, which you can use for the return values.

Another alternative, less efficient but perhaps more "beautiful" and often used in Java is creating a data structure to hold the arguments you need to return, and returning an object with such values.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a map where the key is direction and the value is the number allowed in each direction?  You could create a simple enum to represent the various directions:

```
std::map<Direction, unsigned int>
```

So, in your example, the data in the map would look like this:

```
NORTH -> 1
NORTHEAST -> 2
EAST -> 3
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Return a vector of tuples, with each tuple containing two integers:  the number of squares the piece can move in the x and y directions, respectively.

Doing it that way will allow you to represent knights' movements, castling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the better solution would be to return a `class AllowedMoves`. The data members of this class would be private, and the test functions (e.g. `bool canMoveTo(int row, int col) const;`) would be public. If you later discover that you'd want another internal data format, you can fix that inside the class, without changes everywhere.